# Como criar um autorun?

Tags: windows

Fiz um programa pelo Visual Studio e estou tentando criar um autorun para executá-lo, porém, o executável do programa fica em `\programa\programa\bin\Debug\programa.exe` e o autorun deve ficar na pasta raiz do CD ou imagem.

Este é o problema, como eu poderia fazer o autorun funcionar, já que o executável está em outra pasta?

Comment: Esse caminho `\programa\programa\bin\Debug\programa.exe` é dentro do CD?

Comment: @bfavaretto, sim.

Comment: já tentou: open=programa\programa\bin\Debug\programa.exe ?

Comment: @alacerda, já, mas deu problema, disse que o windows não pode abrir esse tipo de arquivo.

Comment: @Patrick se certificou de usar o caminho relativo?

Comment: Ah, consegui, estava a colocar uma barra antes do caminho... `\programa\programa\bin\Debug\programa.exe`

Comment: @Patrick considere adicionar uma resposta a sua pergunta.

Comment: Importante ressaltar que as versões atuais do Windows só respeitam Auto Run para mídias ópticas. Autorun em HD ou PenDrive será solenemente ignorado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crie um  **autorun.inf** na Pasta raiz do CD
contendo um conteúdo semelhante a este:

```
[autorun]
open=programa\programa\bin\Debug\programa.exe
icon=Autorun.ico
```

Explicação:

- "open=" mostra ao Windows o comando que deve ser executado.
- "icon=" mostra ao Windows que ícone será utilizado para fazer a represnetação da mídia (CD, DVD ou Pen Drive) em Meu Computador ou no Windows Explorer.

A primeira linha "[autorun]" é apenas pra identificar que é um arquivo de autorun e deve ser especificada em todos os arquivos autorun.inf criados.

Fonte:
http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/1077/criando_um_arquivo_autorun.inf

Answer (score 6):

Respondendo um pouco mais do que perguntado, vou apontar algumas opções que tem ao usar o arquivo **autorun.inf**:

**Principais atributos**

- **`action=texto`** opcional: texto do item da execução automática, tanto no menu de contexto, como na janela de execução automática da mídia.
- **`icon=caminho`** caminho do ícone a ser usado para representar a mídia

  É possível fazer referência a um ícone dentro de um pacode de ícones, executável ou dll, colocando uma vírgula + o índice do ícone dentro do arquivo:

  ```
  app\ConsoleApplication.exe,0
  ```
- **`label=texto`** título da mídia que aparece no Explorer
- **`open=caminho`** caminho para execução automática

**Atributos para adição de itens ao menu de contexto**

- `shell=nome_comando_primario` indica qual é o menu primário, que aparece em negrito no menu de contexto, e será usado no duplo clique
- `shell\nome_comando=texto` representa o título da opção de menu nome_comando... podem haver vários títulos para nome_comando`s distintos:

  ```
  shell\comandoA=Título comando A
  shell\comandoB=Título comando B
  ```
- `shell\nome_comando\command=caminho` caminho do executável que deve ser disparado ao clicar no comando específico. Deve haver um para cada título de comando especificado:

  ```
  shell\comandoA\command=app\ConsoleApplication.exe
  shell\comandoB\command=notepad.exe arquivos/leiame.txt
  ```

### Mapa das partes do arquivo Autorun.inf

Abaixo um mapa que mostra onde devem aparecer os textos colocados no arquivo Autorun.inf, assim como a relação entre as propriedades. Usei cores para indicar os elementos relacionados em várias partes.

[image: Mapa de onde os textos devem sair]

**Exemplo completo**

```
[autorun]
action=Executar ConsoleApplication.exe (action)
open=app\ConsoleApplication.exe %0
icon=app\ConsoleApplication.exe,0
label=Título do CD (label)

shell=iniciar

shell\iniciar=Lançar a aplicação (shell\iniciar)
shell\iniciar\command=app\ConsoleApplication.exe %0

shell\leiame=&Ler o aqruivo leiame.txt (shell\leiame)
shell\leiame\command=notepad.exe arquivos/leiame.txt
```

**Aplicação**

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", args));
            Console.WriteLine("Olá mundo!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Como adicionar um ícone na sua aplicação**

Vá nas propriedades do seu projeto executável, na guia Application, daí é só selecionar um arquivo de ícone:

[image: Onde adicionar ícone na aplicação]

**Referência**

[Autorun.inf Entries (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf